# Is the following true or false?

Tags: functional-analysis

I need to prove or counterexample for:

> If  $f\in L^1 ([-\pi,\pi])$ and $\phi(n)$ be an orthonormal sequence and $(f,\phi(n))=0$  for all integers $n$ then $f=0$ a.e.

Comment: What happens if f∈L^1 ?

Comment: Hi! Can you show a bit of your effort or what have you tried/thought so far?

Comment: I suppose $\phi(n)$ could be the zero sequence which not bode well for your conclusion.

Comment: Hi.If φ_n (x)=e^inx/√2π, then f=0 a.e, and I think that the above equation is proved but,do not know how.

Answer (score 1):

An orthonormal sequence $(\phi_n)_{n\geq0}$ consists of functions $$\phi_n\in L^2\bigl([{-\pi},\pi]\bigr)\subset L^1\bigl([{-\pi},\pi]\bigr)$$ with
$$\langle\phi_n,\phi_m\rangle=\delta_{mn}\ .$$
The functions
$$\phi_n(t):={1\over\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{int}\qquad \bigl(n\in{\mathbb Z}\setminus\{0\}\bigr)$$
form (after renumbering) such a sequence. The function $f(t):\equiv1$ is orthogonal to all these $\phi_n$, since
$$\langle f,\phi_n\rangle=\int_0^{2\pi}1\cdot e^{-int}\ dt=0\qquad\forall n\ne0\ .$$
But this  $f$ is not $=0$ almost everywhere. The keyword here is "completeness".

Comment: thank you, but is true (f,ϕn)=0? what?